# How to bind a time value between a property/variable of TS / Angular 8 code and the template/view for: ngx-timepicker-field

Tags: angular, timepicker

This piece of code for *"ngx-timepicker-field"* from the example [here](https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/):

```
    <div class="ngx-timepicker-field-example">
        <ngx-timepicker-field [defaultTime]="'11:11 am'"></ngx-timepicker-field>
    </div>
```

is what I want to use to work with some time values in my code.

From the provided examples or the documentation, it is not clear how to bind a TS/Angular property of e.g. name: `tsTimeA` to the template that allows the following:

1. If user changes time using the up/down arrows or by typing the hour or minute - `tsTimeA` gets updated in the code;
2. If user changes time using the clock interface - `tsTimeA` gets updated in the code;
3. And reversely, if prop. `tsTimeB` changes in the TS code, the `ngx-timepicker-field` also changes in the view;

Would you be so kind and provide some examples for these scenarios for:

- one way binding,
- two way binding,
- and for passing time values via a click / key press or time change events ?